# Only summary data in grafana for blackbox_exporter, not hosts separately

Tags: dashboard, grafana, prometheus

blackbox problem

I added blackbox_exporter in my docker-compose.yml:

```
blackbox_exporter:
  container_name: blackbox_exporter
  image: prom/blackbox-exporter
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "9115:3115"
  networks:
    - monitor-net
  labels:
    org.label-schema.group: "monitoring"
```

I added job into prometheus.yml:

```
- job_name: 'blackbox'
  metrics_path: /probe
  params:
    module: [http_2xx]  # Look for a HTTP 200 response.
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['google.com','amazon.com']   # Target to probe with https.
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__address__]
      target_label: __param_target
    - source_labels: [__param_target]
      target_label: instance
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: blackbox_exporter:9115  # The blackbox exporter's real hostname:port.
```

I added this dashboard in grafana: https://grafana.com/dashboards/5345 because screenshot on this page was exactly what I need.

Alas, I have only summary graphics without legend, without site-specific chapters.

You can see  screenshot here:

[image]

Where my actions were wrong? What can I do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the config you posted, you relabel the blackbox exporter label from `__param_target` to `instance` but the dashboard uses `target` for all the filters and also for the templating variable.

Either change your config to

```
    - source_labels: [__param_target]
      target_label: target
```

or adjust the queries and settings in the dashboard to use `instance`.